# kibana not starting getting error during startup

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana-7

I am using kibana7.5.2 in my application

Below is the dockerfile used

```
FROM node:10.15.2-alpine
LABEL maintainer "AppInfra"

ENV VERSION 7.5.2

ENV PATH /usr/share/kibana/bin:$PATH

ADD kibana-${VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz /usr/share/

RUN mv /usr/share/kibana-$VERSION-linux-x86_64 /usr/share/kibana && \
    addgroup -g 1111 myuser && \
    adduser -D -u 1111 -G myuser myuser && \
    echo "http://mynexusurl:8082/main"  >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    echo "http://mynexusurl:8082/community"  >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk add --no-cache su-exec libc6-compat gcompat && \
    sed -i 's,NODE="${DIR}/node/bin/node",NODE="/usr/local/bin/node",g' /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-plugin && \
    sed -i 's,NODE="${DIR}/node/bin/node",NODE="/usr/local/bin/node",g'  /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana && \
    rm -rf /usr/share/kibana/node && \
    rm -rf /usr/share/kibana/x-pack* && \
    chown -R myuser:myuser /usr/share/kibana


COPY kibana.yml /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /

RUN chmod 755 /docker-entrypoint.sh
USER myuser
#RUN /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana 2>&1 | grep -m 1 "Optimization of .* complete in .* seconds"

WORKDIR /usr/share/kibana

EXPOSE 5601


#USER myuser
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["kibana"]
```

and entrypoint.sh is

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Run as user "kibana" if the command is "kibana"
if [ "$1" = 'kibana' ]
then
if [ "$ELASTICSEARCH_URL" ]
        then
                sed -ri "s!^(\#\s*)?(elasticsearch\.hosts: ).*!\2 [ \"$ELASTICSEARCH_URL\" ]!" /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        fi

fi
exec "$@"
```

environment variable is
ELASTICSEARCH_URL       http://clogstore.storage:9200

Below is the kibana.yml file

```
--- 
elasticsearch.hosts: 
  - "http://elasticsearch:9200"
logging.verbose: true
server.basePath: /clog
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.rewriteBasePath: false
```

If I try to do docker run command my  kibana container is starting and in 10 seconds container is getting stopped with below error

```
Error: EFAULT: bad address in system call argument, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:494:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:333:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:362:19)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:8:15)
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:396:12)
    at PoolWorker.writeEnd (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:129:20)
    at PoolWorker.dispose (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:273:12)
    at WorkerPool.disposeWorkers (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:370:16)
    at WorkerPool.terminate (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:305:10)
    at WorkerPool.disposeWorkers (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:364:12)
    at Timeout.timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:358:44)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:399:8)
    at PoolWorker.writeEnd (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:129:20)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

strange thing is if I uncomment the below line in dockerfile

RUN /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana 2>&1 | grep -m 1 "Optimization of .* complete in .* seconds"

I verified in 7.4.2 kibana its working fine and if I try to do the same thing in kibana  7.5.2 docker build waits at this particular line and even after 3 hrs docker build is not proceeding.

I want to know why am I getting this error.

Whats the significance of this particular line

How to make my kibana container up

If I should add this particular line then how to make it to build fast. build has not completed even once :(

Please help me on this .

I am very new to kibana and I got stuck . I need to make my container up with kibana 7.5.2. Any early help will be really appreciated

Thanks in advance

Note: I tried with kibana 7.5.1 aswel. Getting same issue.

Comment: If you are having problems installing kibana inside an image yourself, I suggest you start with the [official Kibana docker image](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html). You can customize afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dockerfile you're using seems to be building an image from a basic license Kibana download (which includes X-Pack) and then manually removing the x-pack directory. When plugins, such as the ones located in the x-pack directory, are disabled, Kibana needs to rebuild all javascript bundles. This process, known as the optimizer is very memory intensive and depends on the size of the code base, so the amount of memory required can change between releases.

There's a few options:

1. You could try to build your file from a OSS Kibana release, this doesn't include the x-pack plugins and shouldn't require a rebuild of javascript bundles https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/kibana-oss-7-5-2
2. Allocate more memory, 4GB should be enough.
3. Build an intermediate image with at least 4GB memory. After having been built, running the image shouldn't require such high memory usage anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much. this worked. Sorry for very late reply